# convert a single column into tabular format

Tags: regex, shell

I have a file which contains all the entries in a single column like:

```
0
SYSCATSPACE
16384
13432
2948
1
1
TEMPSPACE1
1
1
applicable
1
2
USERSPACE1
4096
1888
2176
1
```

But I want to convert this in a tabular form of `3*6` :

```
0 SYSCATSPACE 16384 13432 2948       1
1 TEMPSPACE1  1     1     applicable 1
2 USERSPACE1  4096  1888  2176       1
```

Can anyone help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 'N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /gp' input
```

which reads 6 lines, replaces newlines with spaces and prints out as a single line. And if you want to align columns you can do so with `column`:

```
sed -n 'N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/ /gp' input | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '$a.="$_ ";if($.%6==0){push(@x,$a);$a=""}END{for(@x){print $_}}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

bash method:

```
while read a; do
    read b; read c; read d; read e; read f;
    echo "$a $b $c $d $e $f"
done
```

NOTE: This is not optimized method, but just one more possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using xargs+printf

```
cat list.txt | xargs -n 6 printf "%10s%20s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n"
```

or, just printf

```
printf "%10s%20s%10s%10s%10s%10s\n" `cat list.txt`
```

based on field length modify the value of `%10s` to a suitable number.

or just xargs+echo+column:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -n 6 echo | column -t
```